# Acrobat PDF calculation with checkbox

Tags: javascript, pdf, checkbox

I've created a PDF form to help create an estimate for plumbing work. There are various lines that the contractor fills in for quanity, cost of the item and then automatically calculates the price for that line; this works fine.

But now I want to add a checkbox to the line that the customer would check if they actually want that work to be done. If they check the box then the price would appear in the final field, otherwise it would display 0.

My fields are:
QtyRow2   ItemCostRow2  CheckboxRow2  PriceRow2

I've tried this Javascript code in the Calculation tab for the PriceRow2 field, but it displays "0" in the price field whether the checkbox is checked or not.

```
var oFldQty = this.getField("QtyRow2");
var oFldItem = this.getField("ItemCostRow2");

if (this.getField("CheckboxRow2").isBoxChecked(0)) {
    nSubTotal = oFldQty.value * oFldItem.value;
} else {
    nSubTotal = 0;
}

event.value = nSubTotal;
```

How should I modify this to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the whole code in the calculation, it would be way safer to define nSubTotal; otherwise, it gets defined as a global variable, and can behave strangely.

Also, whenever this calculation runs, and the test results to false, nSubTotal is set to 0. That means, you have to define nSubTotal, and then add to it while you work through the form.

If you want to simply have a result in the field, there is no need to do the detour via a variable; you can set event.value in the true and the false path.

For a single checkbox, it is IMHO easier to use its value (or its "unchecked" value for portability of the code reasons). This leads to the following code snippet:

```
if (this.getField("CheckboxRow").value != "Off") {
    // box is checked
    event.value = oFldQtyty.value * oFldItem.value ;
} else {
    // box is unchecked
    event.value = 0 ;
}
```

And that should do it.

However, as you have a table, it is best practice to consolidate all calculations into one single script, which can be attached to a hidden read-only field which is not even involved in the calculation itself. This gives you much better overview and control over the calculation, and prevents calculation order errors.